# NodeJS rest API running on AppEngine Latency issue

Tags: node.js, performance, google-app-engine, digital-ocean, latency

Currently my rest api build with Express in node is running on Digital Ocean. I'm doing the switch to Google App Engine.

When I run my  API on Digital Ocean, for a specific request the response time is 46MS. The same request on App Engine is 706MS.

I'm wondering if I have misconfigured something ...

I'm using the flex environment. The configuration for 1 instance is:

cpu: 8
memory_gb: 32
disk_size_gb: 50

Does anyone has any idea on why I get a huge response time like that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would recommend you to do is checking the region and zone in which you GAE app has been deployed, maybe the default region and zone is not the best for your app, as stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/#choosing_a_region_and_zone) you might want to choose a region or zone that is close to your point of service to decrease network latency.

If after checking that and selecting the region and zone that suits best for your app you are still experiencing the same latency issue please add more details on what tasks is the instance performing and maybe provide some sample code to understand the situation better.

Comment: If this answer solved your question could you please accept it? Just so it gets more visibility for the other users that might have the same issue.